# Php XML query with spaces in tag names

Tags: php, xml

Ive had a search around but I cant see a answer to this one, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I am accessing an rest api and returning XML in php using curl.

I have an issue when getting values form tags with spaces in the names, here is some of the xml i get back.

```
    <extension_attribute>
  <id>66</id>
  <name>ASSET - EMAIL</name>
  <type>String</type>
  <value>email@email.email</value>
</extension_attribute>
```

I can get the value back using something like this:

```
$xml->extension_attributes->extension_attribute[7]->value;
```

But sadly im not in charge of the attribute names, there being created by different team who wont remove the spaces.

I did try searching using children("...") but no luck.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but ...which _spaces_ do you mean?

Comment: I am meaning the spaces in the tag <name> round the -

Comment: Also, what seems to be the problem? Are you asking for some help with your code, because you have already said that you CAN access the values, so what is wrong?

Comment: @Bob Bryden, that's perfectly valid, as the spaces are in the value not the tag...

Comment: I can access any element by name so long as there are no spaces in the name. eg `$model = $xml->hardware->model;` But not with the spaces in the name. so `$model = $xml->extension_attributes->ASSET - EMAIL;` will not work.

Comment: But there are no spaces in the name, the spaces are in the value, and that should not cause you any issues. What exactly are you trying to do when you get the error, and what error do you get?

Comment: if I use this code `$pickedup = $xml->extension_attributes->extension_attribute[7]->value;` the value is Yes.

If i use this code `$pickedup = $xml->extension_attributes->Asset - Device Collected;` I get this error:

` PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Collected' (T_STRING) in index.php on line 69`

Comment: Those are not tags, but the text contents of a tag. E.g. `ASSET - EMAIL` is the node value/text contents of the tag <name>. You'd access it via `$xml->extension_attributes->extension_attribute[ $i ]->name`.

Answer (score 0):

The string `"ASSET - EMAIL"` is not a tag name, but the contents of text node. You can not address it using SimpleXMLs syntax sugar.

However, with an Xpath expression it is possible.

```
$root = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
foreach ($root->xpath('//extension_attribute[name = "ASSET - EMAIL"]') as $attribute) {
  var_dump((string)$attribute->value);
}
```

Output:

```
string(17) "email@email.email"
```

The Xpath expression selects any `extension_attribute` element node...

```
`//extension_attribute`
```

and filters for the nodes with a child element `name` that has the text content `ASSET - EMAIL`

```
`//extension_attribute[name = "ASSET - EMAIL"]`
```

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will always return an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects. The array will be empty if no nodes are matched by the expression.

In DOM, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values from Xpath expressions, too:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//extension_attribute[name = "ASSET - EMAIL"]/value)')
);
```

The Xpath function `string()` will cast the first matched node to a string and return it. If no node was matched, it will return an empty string.